# categorizing items with jquery

Tags: jquery

Am creating a shelf of books on my site but am having a problem placing each item on a row in the shelf. What i want is for jquery to help me create a new ul tag to conatin  a new but continuing list of the items each row is supposed to carry 5 books each, how can i make jquery know the number of books and then arrange them in the manner i just said? Thanks to anyone that helps.

This is how i want it to look.

```
<ul>

<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>

</ul>

<ul>

<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>
<li>Book</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean to split a single `<ul>` list into several lists with 5 elements each?

Comment: What would your HTML initially look like?

Comment: no i want it to create ten ul tags and input five elements each.

Comment: The initial look can just be one ul tag with about 50 elements in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="original">
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
        <li>Book</li>
    </ul>
</div>
​
```

You can do something like this:

```
while ($("ul.original li").size()) {
    var $slice = $("ul.original li").slice(0, 5);
    $("<ul>").append($slice.clone()).appendTo(".container");
    $slice.remove();
}

$("ul.original").remove();​
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/XwPxR/).